# rendering applicative form in yesod

Tags: haskell, yesod

When I render (with renderDivs or renderTable) an applicative form all fields are rendered vertically.

I want to make a form with several lines but also with several fields in each line.

Can I do that without working with html directly?

Comment: If you use monadic forms you have flexibility over the layout.

Comment: Well, yes, I made it this way. But it seems that it is rather natural requirement to have horisontal rendering. I am totally unexperienced in html and I was in debt if there some special render in Yesod or e.g. some css-stuff to do that more elegant. It seems that it is not the case.

Comment: Bear in mind that `renderDivs` and `renderTable` simply convert the AForm to an MForm then set the layout in the monadic form. See if you can write a function that takes `[[AForm ...]]` and lays them out with the inner lists as unstructured rows and the whole list as a column. This would solve your problem once and for all.